# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient,

Tags: android, flutter

I can't run the app on the emulator or on a real device. When I try to run the app from VS Code, it shows this error message:

[image: screenshot of debug console]

I tried uninstalling the app and doing `flutter clean`.

Comment: Did you tried to clear data of the emulator and then try to run?

Comment: actually I didn't find  specific block of code where issues comes from.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This error just happened to me when I launched the app in the store. I'm correcting it now, change the Location library to Gelocator.

At first I thought it was an error in Flutter 3.7.0, I lowered the version to 3.3.10 and 3.3.9 and the same problem continued. My solution was to change the location library to geolocator. It has almost the same functions, I only had to make a few changes.

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: yeah also just started getting this today. Mine is from a flutter app when trying to use location services

Comment: This error just happened to me when I launched the app in the store. I'm correcting it now, change the Location library to Gelocator.

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Comment: Same issue. Any solution? If I downgrade location library version will it help?

Comment: At first I thought it was an error in Flutter 3.7.0, I lowered the version to 3.3.10 and 3.3.9 and the same problem continued. My solution was to change the location library to geolocator. It has almost the same functions, I only had to make a few changes.

Comment: Removing the location library also solved my problem.

Comment: you are right. i change package and issues are gone

Comment: How are you requesting the GPS Service? I cannot find any alternative other than the location package.

Comment: @L.Goyal Do you mean to raise the gps service? ask you to activate your location?

Comment: Could you please help any alternative for Native android application? Because this solution did not work for me in native android app.

Comment: Faced the same error after using   location: ^4.4.0 and geolocator: ^10.1.0, in same project, but after updating to  location: ^5.0.3 geolocator: ^10.1.0 error fixed

Comment: No need to change the location library to a geolocator. This issue has been fixed in the location library itself just upgrade the library to version 5.0.0 or above.

Answer (score 59):

No need to change the package I was also facing this issue I just fixed it:

1. Go into  C:\Users\Qc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-4.4.0\android\build.gradle    :
   changed "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+" to "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1" works

   dependencies {
   api '"com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
   implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   }
2. List item In project at android level go into build.gradle and add this line:
   [image]

Update: added the required code

```
  configurations.all{
      resolutionStrategy{
         force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
      }
 }
```

Comment: I only needed to do step 2 - adding the section to the build.gradle file

Comment: For mine also the 2 step is helpful. Thanks

Comment: For Macbook packages folder address for your Flutter project will be like following:  flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/

Comment: number 2 is the one!

Comment: Thank you guys, step 2 was sufficient ❤️

Comment: Just to mention where the Build.gradle is located. It is in: project/android/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks! Number 2 made it. The issue was caused by using background_locator and geolocator together on a flutter project

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my life. the step2 worked for me. it worked for RN project.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me. the step2 worked for me. it worked for RN project. –

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the location 5.0.0 version. Just try to upgrade your location library version 5.0.0 or above to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -4):

in my case, got to C:\Users\Md Emarat Hossain\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-4.4.0\android\build.gradle and changed "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+" to "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1" works