# Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.a, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.a' appears in base.apk

Tags: flutter, google-maps

my production app is crashing and this is the crash log i got but unable to find any solution. I am using Flutter 3.7.1

```
Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.a, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.a' appears in base.apk)
   at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.setActivity(FlutterLocation.java:32)
   at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService.setActivity(FlutterLocationService.java:6)
   at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.dispose(LocationPlugin.java:50)
   at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.detachActivity(LocationPlugin.java)
   at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.onDetachedFromActivity(LocationPlugin.java)
   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.detachFromActivity(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:33)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:58)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onDestroy(FlutterActivity.java:18)
   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8571)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1364)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5937)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5995)
   at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:47)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273823/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interface-com-google-android-gms-l