# Why does setting `myLocationEnabled` in `MapboxMap()` to `true` crash my Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, location, mobile-application, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to run a Flutter app (on Android) that features a `MapboxMap` Widget. The app works flawlessly unless I uncomment `myLocationEnabled: true`, which causes the app to crash after the debug console spits out 158 lines of error messages. As far as I know, I've properly configured every file in the "Android" folder to allow location to be collected.

Environment:

- Pixel 7 Pro via wireless ADB
- Flutter on Ubuntu in Docker (but the same problem occurs outside of the container)
- `mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0`
- `permission_handler: ^10.3.0`

Is there any known fix to this problem, or will I have to use something like `geolocator` to collect the location data myself? That would be doable but painfully inelegant for a map-based app like this.

Between AI-generated files, online tutorials, Stack Overflow questions, and weeks of work, I've tried dozens of different implementations and have yet to find anything that works. I've also tried other APIs, such as `mapbox_maps_flutter` and webview-linked `mapbox-gl-js`. Among many other error messages, this one seems most prevalent (I've included the stack-trace for context):

```
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407): java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient, but class was expected (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient' appears in /data/app/~~gb-5muDWr4YgcgsimCcKAQ==/com.mvp1.dsco-97NaE_OWQAZrtRkBhF9zRQ==/base.apk)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:58)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngineImpl.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleLocationEngineImpl.java:26)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProxy.requestLocationUpdates(LocationEngineProxy.java:34)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.onLocationLayerStart(LocationComponent.java:1439)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.enableLocationComponent(LocationComponent.java:1568)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(LocationComponent.java:551)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.enableLocationComponent(MapboxMapController.java:274)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.updateMyLocationEnabled(MapboxMapController.java:1563)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController.access$100(MapboxMapController.java:91)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxgl.MapboxMapController$1.onStyleLoaded(MapboxMapController.java:141)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.notifyStyleLoaded(MapboxMap.java:963)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap.onFinishLoadingStyle(MapboxMap.java:225)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1383)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapChangeReceiver.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapChangeReceiver.java:198)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(NativeMapView.java:1166)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/Mbgl-MapChangeReceiver(29407):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273823/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interface-com-google-android-gms-l) didn't help, so I'm unsure of what this error means or how it can be resolved. As far as I can tell, it's occurring somewhere inside the `mapbox_gl` api, which leads me to believe others have experienced this issue.

Just in case it's not caused by `mapbox_gl`, however, I've included my current, simple version of `map_page.dart` below. (I don't know whether this means anything, but the message "DEBUG | `_onMapCreated()` called" inside `_onMapCreated()` is shown in the debug console just before any error messages pop up.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPage({super.key});

  @override
  MapPageState createState() => MapPageState();
}

class MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  // Imports the necessary Mapbox data from 'gradle.properties'.
  static const accessToken =
      String.fromEnvironment("MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN", defaultValue: "");
  static const mapStyle = String.fromEnvironment("MAPBOX_STYLE_URL",
      defaultValue: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v11");

  late bool _locationRequested;
  late bool _locationEnabled;

  MapboxMapController? _mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _locationRequested = false;
    _locationEnabled = false;

    _getLocationPermission();
  }

  /// Reloads the page once location has been requested and enabled.
  Future<void> _getLocationPermission() async {
    if (!_locationRequested) await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();

    bool locationGranted = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.isGranted;

    setState(() {
      _locationRequested = true;
      _locationEnabled = locationGranted;
    });
  }

  /// Calls `_buildMap()` if location is enabled;
  /// shows a loading circle otherwise.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget content =
        _locationEnabled ? _buildMap() : const CircularProgressIndicator();

    return Center(child: content);
  }

  /// Builds and displays the Mapbox map.
  /// (This can only be called if location is enabled.)
  Widget _buildMap() {
    return MapboxMap(
      // Until the camera starts tracking the user's location,
      // the map will center on Athens, Greece.
      initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(37.983810, 23.727539),
        zoom: 12.0,
      ),
      accessToken: accessToken,
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      styleString: mapStyle,
      myLocationEnabled: true, //! Enabling this crashes the app
      myLocationTrackingMode: MyLocationTrackingMode.Tracking,
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    debugPrint("DEBUG | `_onMapCreated()` called");
    // setState(() => _mapController = controller);
    _mapController = controller;
  }
}
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any solutions for this I am facing same issue.